# tkinter image not displaying despite not being collected

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, photoimage

the following won t display anything:

```
def pic(name):
    def p(image=[]): #keep a reference to the image, but only load after creating window
        if not image: 
            image.append(PhotoImage("../pic/small/"+name+".png")) 
        return image[0]
    def do(canvas, point, angle, size, fill, outline):
        canvas.create_image(*point, image=p(), tag="visual")
    return do

flame = pic("flame")

flame(canvas, (100, 200), 0, 30, "red", "blue")
```

The second time I m calling flame, p still remembers its image. No Exceptions occur, yet the image doesn t show up.

however:

```
_pic2 = PhotoImage(file="../pic/small/flame.png")
canvas.create_image(300, 200, image=_pic2)
```

does work

(I m aware there are some unused arguments, but pic needs the same signature as other functions that need them

```
def do(canvas, point, *_):
```

would be just as good)

(pic, flame, _pic2, canvas) are global

Comment: Aren't you just missing the `file` keyword parameter? `PhotoImage(file="...")` instead of `PhotoImage("...")` Without it, the path is the "name" of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems not to be the image being garbage collected at all. You are just missing the `file` parameter name, thus the path is used as the image's "name" instead.

Using `PhotoImage(file="../pic/small/"+name+".png")` should fix it.

However, speaking of garbage collection, you don't actually need the inner `p` function with the list parameter. This is one of the rare cases where you can just define the `PhotoImage` as a local variable in the function, as it will remain in the scope of the `do` function even after the `pic` function has exited, and thus will not be garbage collected.

```
def pic(name):
    img = PhotoImage(file="../pic/small/"+name+".png")
    def do(canvas, point, angle, size, fill, outline):
        canvas.create_image(*point, image=img, tag="visual")
    return do
```

(It *will* be collected when `flame` is collected, though, but the same is true for your approach. But as you said `flame` is global, this should not be a problem.)

Comment: I actually do need the inner p function, not for gc but to delay loading the image until it is possible to do so (no idea why that is necessary though)